# No comprendo porque no funciona mi elemento <input> con mi JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

estoy tratando de desarrollar un pequeño ejercicio de JQuery básico de un libro, se supone que al  arrastrar una barra debajo del texto en la pagina, se supone que el tamaño de la fuente se incrementa, pero por alguna razón no pasa nada.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery2</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/JQuery2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

   <div id="theText">Hello!</div>
   <form id="controller">
       <label for="sizer"></label><input type="range" id="sizer" max="100" min="10" >
   </form>

</body>
</html>
```

********JAVASCRIPT***************************************

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#sizer').change(function() {
        $('#theText').css('font-size',$('#sizer').val());
    });
});
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pues vas bien. Solo falta decirle al font size que son pixeles los que les estas pasando. Lo unico es concatenarle los `px` para eso lo haces con  +  `+ 'px'`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#sizer').change(function() {
        $('#theText').css('font-size',$('#sizer').val() + 'px');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery2</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/JQuery2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

   <div id="theText">Hello!</div>
   <form id="controller">
       <label for="sizer"></label><input type="range" id="sizer" max="100" min="10" >
   </form>

</body>
</html>
```